# Маршрут вдоль реки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть ли возможность прокладывать маршрут вдоль рек?

Comment: А какую задачу вы хотите решить в конечном счете?

Comment: известны точки причалов и нужно между ними проложить путь вдоль москвы реки, что бы показать маршрут корабля.

Answer (score 2):

В API Яндекс.Карт нет готовой речной навигации. Вы можете самостоятельно составить граф переходов для нужной области и написать функцию маршрутизации для точек причалов.